# Why is the order of output of a C program different when its stdout is redirected to a file?

Tags: c, linux, output, io-redirection

Here is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    system("uname");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output.

```
$ gcc foo.c
$ ./a.out 
Hello
Linux
```

However, if I redirect the output of the program to a file, I see that the order of the output is reversed, i.e. `Linux` is printed before `Hello`.

```
$ ./a.out > out.txt
$ cat out.txt
Linux
Hello
```

Why is the order of the output different when redirection is involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because stdout is buffered in different ways. When you call your program without the redirection, the buffering defaults to linewise buffering. In the second call, the buffer is much larger, and get written when your program terminates. Since your call to `uname` terminated before, this output now shows up earlier in the file. When you depend on the ordering, you can either explicit call `fflush(stdout)` after your `printf` call, or you can call `uname` via `popen` and print its output explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Since buffering is done on the terminal, the order of output might be different.

Comment: Wrong. Even if terminal does buffering (I think not), it has only one "input sink": reordering of data can not happen there.